# Looking for a simpler JavaScript timer

Tags: javascript, timer-jobs

Right now i have a text-based game that deals with turns, but i want to upgrade it to a timer system so that when the timer hits 0 then you gain 1 or 2 of whatever action you were doing. Also if you know how to make it randomly pick whether u get 1 item or 2 items could you please elaborate on how to do that? Thank you to all responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) for delaying actions for a set period of time, or [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) if you wish to run it periodically on a given interval.

For getting a random number either 1 or 2 you can use [`random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random):

```
var randomOneOrTwo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you will get from here.

http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/

Happy Coding.....